# Ray optics : Circular mirror with reflecting surface on the inside

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

A light ray enters through an infintely small hole and gets reflected as shown.

1. After how many reflections will it emerge out again? (It can come out in any orientation).
2. Will it emerge out for any angle θ? If not, then why?

   [image])

Comment: is it homework ?

Comment: ( NB: there is a long and a direct answer :-) )

Comment: Hint: watch all the possible angles to normal that exists in your scheme.

Comment: It may or may not emerge - there is a probability for both of them. Light ray will emerge in case of ideal mirror where there will be no absorption. But in real world, every surface has a certain absorptive power, resulting in decrease in intensity of the light ray. This is normally observed in black-bodies...... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body

Comment: This is purely a geometry + number theory exercice ;-) Indeed, it should have been posted in maths.

Comment: It was a science quiz question from my class. My teacher asked after how many reflections would the light ray come out for i=9°. I imagined that the light rays would form a star like pattern and hence it would emerge at 180/9 =20th reflection. The answer was right. But I want a generic answer for any angle i.

Comment: My teacher asked this question during a quiz, for a specific case(i=9°) I just took i=45° and got the answer as 3. So, I thought the answer would be 180/9=20 and it turned out to be right. But it is really bugging me. So, if 'i' is not a divisor of 180°, would the light ray never come out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bounces draw a finite star, then by symmetry the ray goes out (it's where the star get closed). This case is for angle $a$ between 2 bounces ( $a =  \pi-2\theta$ ) is such that $ka=0[2\pi]$, i.e. when there exist $k$ and $n$ such that $a=\frac{n2\pi}{k}$, i.e. when $\frac{a}{2\pi}$ is a fraction ( or equivalently, $\frac{\theta}{\pi}$ ).

If not, an infinite amount of locations will be visited but the ray will never come back to the hole... If we assume the hole is not larger than a mathematical point.

Comment: Could you please post a rough diagram as well? (a MS Paint image would suffice)

Comment: I can do better: here is an interactive desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zh34e6udgi  for the 100 first bounces (or edit max t value in the first cell). Then, just play with b. :-)

Comment: That was a really good one! Thanks. Solution accepted